# How to override MuiTypography-colorTextPrimary in createMuiTheme?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I want to override the default black color for text in MaterialUI components (I try to implement a dark theme for a site) but don't know exactly what I should specify in the theme. This is my code. The style that appears applied when checking in Developer Tools is

```
.MuiTypography-colorTextPrimary {
    color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.87);
}
```

My code:

```
const darkTheme = createMuiTheme({
  overrides: {
    MuiCssBaseline: {
    "@global": {
      color: "#ffffff"
     }
    },
    MuiTypography: {
      colorTextPrimary: '#ffffff',
      root: {
        color: '#ffffff',
      }
    palette: {
      root: {
        color: '#ffffff'
      },
      text: {
         primary: '#fff',
         secondary: '#fff',
         disabled: '#fff'
      },
      primary: {
        light: "#ffffff",
        main: "#ffffff", //depOrange
        dark: "#ffffff",
        myColor: "#dddddd",
      },
      secondary: {
        main: "#F05454", //gray
      },
      table: {
        header: "#fe5544",
      },
      link: {
        main: "#222233",
      },
      third: {
        main: "#555555",
      },
      background: {
        paper: "#222831"
      }, 
      text: {
        default: '#fff',
      },
      error:
      {
        contrastText: "#fff",
        dark: "#333333",
        main: "#366666",
        light: "#eeeeee"

      },
      warning:
      {
        contrastText: "#fff",
        dark: "#333333",
        main: "#366666",
        light: "#eeeeee"

      },
      info:
      {
        contrastText: "#fff",
        dark: "#333333",
        main: "#366666",
        light: "#eeeeee"

      },
      success:
      {
        contrastText: "#fff",
        dark: "#333333",
        main: "#366666",
        light: "#eeeeee"

      }
    },
    typography: {
      fontFamily: "Segoe UI",
      button: {
        fontFamily: [
          "-apple-system",
          "BlinkMacSystemFont",
          '"Segoe UI"',
          "Roboto",
          '"Helvetica Neue"',
          "Arial",
          "sans-serif",
          '"Apple Color Emoji"',
          '"Segoe UI Emoji"',
          '"Segoe UI Symbol"',
        ].join(","),
        fontSize: "1rem",
      },
      color: "#fff"
    },
  });
```

The styles are applied(some of them work but not the one for the text color)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To override color for Mui-Typography, try:

```
const theme = createTheme({
components: {
  MuiTypography: {
    styleOverrides: {
      root: {
        color: "red"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

You can check [this sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/override-mui-typography-q5i0q?file=/src/App.js:176-349) for the example.

In order to create a dark theme, the documentation recommends togging color mode like [the example here](https://mui.com/customization/dark-mode/). I've created something similar in [this codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/dark-light-mode-cdvdp?file=/src/App.js) with typography and it works.